# Need special validation for shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, scripting

I want to create a bash script which will have lot of options while executing.

```
# script.sh  --dry-run --user <parameter1> --pass <parameter2>
```

I heard about getopt option but looks like we can only write either `--user or --password` or `--dry-run` and not all of them. Basically I want to take `--user parameter1` as input1 and `--pass parameter2` as input2 and a special case where if `--dry-run` option is there, then execute only dry-run code instead of production.

```
#!/bin/bash
user=$1
pass=$2

help() {
    cat<<EOF
Usage : $0 --dry-run --user <user_id> --pass <password>
you can specify --dry-run or --production
EOF
}

[ ${3} ] || help

function dry_run() {
    // --dry-run code 
}

function production() {
   // --production code 
}
```

I want to validate `--dry-run` and if the option is `--dry-run`, then execute function `dry_run()` else execute `production()` function.
But how to write options and validations ?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Sure you can specify multiple long options. It is just how you process them if specifying multiple make sense or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood what you're after, you can do it with `getopt`:

```
#!/bin/bash

PARAMS=$(getopt -l dry-run,production,user:,pass: -n $0 "" -- "$@")
if [ $? != 0 ]; then exit 1; fi
eval set -- "$PARAMS"

dryrun=false

while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    case "$1" in
        --dry-run) dryrun=true; shift;;
        --production) dryrun=false; shift;;
        --user) user="$2"; shift 2;;
        --pass) pass="$2"; shift 2;;
        --) shift;;
        *) exit 1;;
    esac
done

if [ $dryrun = true ]; then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

You can add more processing if you want to forbid specifying both `--dry-run` and `--production`, or if `--user` and `--password` are required.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `getopt` to handle script long-options. The `getopts` builtin function can do it as well *(and usually without subshells)*. The trick is to use `-` as an option. That way `--dry-run` *(for example)* becomes `optvar=-` and `OPTARG=-dry-run`. Here's a functional example of how you might do it specifically for this case:

```
#!/bin/sh
help(){ echo usage; }                       #dummy help
unset   user dryrun pass _o o               #ensure all flag vars are unset
while   getopts :-:u:p:d o              &&  #getopts loop
        o=${o#-}        _o=${o:+$OPTARG}    #empty $o if $o==-
do      case            $o$OPTARG       in  #test concatenated $o$OPTARG
        (u*|-user)      user=${_o:-$2}  ;;  #set $user to $_o or $2
        (p*|-pass)      pass=${_o:-$2}  ;;  #ditto for $pass
        (d*|-dryrun)    o=d dryrun=1    ;;  #no $OPTARG either way - o=d base
        (*)             !  help         ;;  #no usage options met - opt error
        esac || exit                        #quit with error if opt == ! help
        shift "$((!${#o}+(OPTIND-(OPTIND=1))))"  #shift params as they're read
done
```

This will run as is. In fact I tried several different option possibilities with it. For example:

```
~/getopts.sh -p-user --user me -uyou -d --dry-run
```

...when run w/ a `#!/bin/sh -x` bangline printed this to my stderr:

```
+ unset user dryrun pass _o o
+ getopts :-:u:p:d o
+ o=p _o=-user
+ pass=-user
+ shift 1
+ getopts :-:u:p:d o
+ o= _o=
+ user=me
+ shift 2
+ getopts :-:u:p:d o
+ o=u _o=you
+ user=you
+ shift 1
+ getopts :-:u:p:d o
+ o=d _o=
+ o=d dryrun=1
+ shift 1
+ getopts :-:u:p:d o
+ o= _o=
+ o=d dryrun=1
+ shift 1
+ getopts :-:u:p:d o
```

After completing the `getopts` loop you can just do...

```
[ "$((dryrun))" -eq 0 ] && production || dryrun
```

...if you have declared the `production()` and `dryrun()` functions. They'll find any command-line values specified for `$pass` and/or `$user` assigned as necessary. If either of those has not been declared on the command-line, you might consider referencing them like:

```
echo "${user=default_username}" "${pass=default_password}"
```

...just to cover all of your bases.